# python typing: result depending on arguments

Tags: python, python-typing, typing, python-3.10

I have a function:

```
T = typing.TypeVar('T', str, list[str])
def f(arg: T) -> T:
    ...
```

AFAICS this means the following are valid:

- `f(str)` → `str`
- `f(list[str])` → `list[str]`

or in other words when a string is given, a string is returned; when a list of strings is given, a list of strings is returned.

Now I would like to express the type of a function that when a single string is given returns a `bool`, and if a list of strings is given returns a `list[bool]`.

How would I go about that?

Comment: Would `overload` be useful in this case? https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload

Comment: Thank you @koyeung – that did the trick. I made an answer out of this.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the hint in comments by @koyeung

```
@typing.overload
def f(arg: str) -> bool:
    ...

@typing.overload
def f(arg: list[str]) -> list[bool]:
    ...

def f(arg):
    if isinstance(arg, list):
        return ...  # implementation for list
    ... # implementation for str
```